# ID not aligning center CSS [outlook.com]

Tags: html, css, outlook

I am having trouble centering an ID in the login page of outlook.com. The ID of the login box is #signInTD. I have tried using the 'right' style to center it. However, I have managed to make it look like it is in the center but I want to make sure that it is in the center when looking at it from bigger screen or browser. What should I use to achieve this?

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4sm3uwhb/2/) link to the login box.

Thanks.

This is what I have tried.

```
#signInID {right: -195px !important;}
```

Comment: Where is the code? It's very messy in the fiddle. You've tried with right: .... but what is the position property for that elem? It has no effect if the position is static, in that case you can use margin-right instead of right.

Comment: Sorry that it is messy. I had to put all that code otherwise it didn't look right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :-

Add this class

```
#signInTD.floatLeft{float:none}
#signInTD{margin:0 auto}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/THE_MukulKant/4sm3uwhb/4/)**

Comment: Thank you so much :) Been trying to get this working for a while haha